# Is Burgess' ST theory an algebraic set theory? If it is, what kind of algebras are described by this theory?

Tags: set-theory, universal-algebra

I found the mention of Burgess' ST set theory in the article  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_set_theory about George Boolos' generalized set theory (GST). It sounds like this: "ST is GST with the axiom schema of specification replaced by the axiom of empty set."

If I am reading this correctly, then ST has these axioms:

1. Axiom of Extensionality: The sets x and y are the same set if they have the same members.
2. Axiom of empty set: there exists an empty set.
3. Axiom of Adjunction: If x and y are sets, then there exists a set w, the adjunction of x and y, whose members are just y and the members of x:

   ∀ x ∀ y ∃ w ∀ z [ z ∈ w ↔ ( z ∈ x ∨ z = y ) ] .

Due to the axiom of adjunction, an operation, which is known as "Tarski' adjunction operation", can be defined like this:
$$
x  \triangleright  y \leftrightharpoons x \cup \{y\} 
$$

Obviously, the membership relation can be defined like this
$$
x \in y \leftrightharpoons y \triangleright x = y,
$$

and the axiom or extensionality can be re-written so that it does not contain the membership symbol "$\in$".

Presented in this manner, ST theory looks like a theory of algebras of the signature containing the nullary symbol "$\varnothing$" and the binary symbol  "$\triangleright$" and this is an algebraic theory. Are their any problems with this statement? If there aren't, then the next question naturally arises: what kind of algebras are described by this theory?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by an “algebraic theory”?

Comment: Anyway, it’s quite unclear what answer do you expect other than “the theory describes the class of algebras that satisfy the given axioms”.

Comment: Also, the theory is not “Burgess’s” in any way; this is just the Adjunctive set theory, which goes back to at least the work of Tarski and Szmielew from the 1950’s. Wikipedia just refers to Burgess’s book because it is a convenient recent reference monograph.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_theory, an algebraic theory is a theory that uses axioms stated entirely in terms of equations between terms with free variables. However an ``algebraic set theory'' might be understantood differently from this, because the extensionality axiom looks more like a definition of the symbol '=' than a statement.  Thus, I formulated my question in the form I did in order to judge by the answers how other mathematicians treat this notion and whether or not ST is an algebraic set theory in their treatment.

Comment: I believe, the extensionality axiom in any set theory  will create the same problem with interpretation of the term "algebraic theory", as with ST. Probably, this question should have been asked in more general terms, but I don't know the appropriate  terminology to formulate such question in general terms.

Comment: The Wikipedia article is using some unusual terminology, these are usually called *equational theories*. ST is very far from being an equational theory. Extensionality is indeed the first problem: this is not even a universal sentence, only $\forall\exists$, and it is impossible to get rid of the existential quantifier by adding some more definable functions into the language (this would be tantamount to a definable global choice function, something not available even in ZFC). But the other axioms of ST are not at all equational either: the axiom of the empty set, $\forall x\;x\notin 0$, ...

Comment: ... translates to the inequation $\varnothing\triangleright x\ne\varnothing$, and the adjunction axiom $z\in x\cup\{y\}\to z\in x\lor z=y$ is not even a Horn clause: $(x\triangleright y)\triangleright z=x\triangleright y\to x\triangleright  z=x\lor z=y$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek. Your answers, even though not posted as ``answers'', have been very useful to me. I also searched in literature and now, based on your comments and on what I read, I am better prepared to ask  one or two better formulated questions on this topic.