# Is the theory of the adjunction operation, used for algebraization of hereditarily finite set theory, algebraizable?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

The operation used for algebraization of hereditarily finite set theory is named adjunction in 〈A. Tarski, S. Givant, *[A Formalization of Set Theory without Variables](https://doi.org/10.1090/coll/041)*, Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society. 1987〉 and its infix sign is this: “$\rhd$”. Even though the adjunction is represented in a different manner (by using punctuation signs) in the paper 〈L. Kirby, *[Finitary Set Theory](https://doi.org/10.1215/00294527-2009-009)*, Notre Dame Journal of Formal Logic Volume 50, Number 3, 2009.〉, this paper is a nice presentation of the theory of inheritably finite sets.

The adjunction operation can be expressed through union and singleton like this

$$x \rhd y = x \cup \{y\}.$$

However, the axiom stating the existence of this operation (i.e. stating that for any two sets $x$, $y$,  the set $x \rhd y$ exists.) was formulated way earlier in 〈Bernays, Paul (1937), *[A System of Axiomatic Set Theory—Part I](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0022481200040135)*, The Journal of Symbolic Logic, Association for Symbolic Logic, 2 (1): 65–77〉 as an axiom of a formulation of set theory in Bernays's terms, like this:

$$\forall x \forall y \exists u \forall z\ (z\in u\leftrightarrow(z\in x\lor z=y)).$$

My question is whether the theory in the language with two symbols “$\in$” and “$=$”, with this axiom as well as the axioms for “=” is algebraizable. I will name this theory “pure adjunctive theory” (PAT) for the reasons below.

Usually, they name “adjunctive set theory” this theory plus the axiom of existence of empty set, and when they also add the extensionality axiom they denote the resulting theory  “ST”. But I am interested in “algebraizability” more than in other aspects, like those which served as reason to add axioms to Bernays' axiom and study the resulting theory.

The empty set axiom is usually added to PAT, since without it, the natural numbers could not be represented in the theory. But I am more interested to learn how the PAT theory with atoms, including with Quine atoms, will look like. Thus, my question is about PAT without other axioms added to it.

An important remark is that I am not sure what is “algebraization of set theory” and I am expecting to learn this from your answers (see also my other question [What is "algebraic theory" in the wide sense?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306165/what-is-algebraic-theory-in-the-wide-sense)).

Comment: If you mean "algebraic theory" in the sense of universal algebra, then what are we to do about the relation symbol $\in$? If you mean the more general notion of an algebraic theory as a monad, then I believe this can be done (but the choice of particular operations disappears).

Comment: Ah! We have $x \in y \iff y = y \cup \{x\}$, so it is doable.

Answer (score 2):

To get things started, consider an algebraic theory with a binary symbol $\triangleright$, and axioms (where $x \triangleright y \triangleright z = (x \triangleright y) \triangleright z$):

\begin{align*}
z \triangleright x \triangleright y &= z \triangleright y \triangleright x\\
y \triangleright x \triangleright x &= y \triangleright x
\end{align*}

We may introduce some abbreviations:

- $x \in y$ stands for $y = y \triangleright x$
- $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ stands for $\emptyset \triangleright x_1 \triangleright \cdots \triangleright x_n$

We are not done, however, because it introduce $\emptyset$ and state $\forall x \,.\, x \not\in \emptyset$ in an algebraic way. We could do it if we had binary $\cup$, but that is not exprssible using only $\triangleright$. Indeed, there are models which are closed under $\triangleright$ (interpreted as adjoining an element to a set) but not under binary unions.

Comment: Your axiom $\emptyset\triangleright x\triangleright y=x\triangleright y$ is not valid. Also, you are missing the adjunction axiom $z\in x\cup\{y\}\to z\in x\lor z=y$, which is even worse than $x\notin\emptyset$; cf. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408327/is-burgess-st-theory-an-algebraic-set-theory-if-it-is-what-kind-of-algebras-a#comment1047481_408327.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the offending axiom. I did say "to get things started"... I am a bit confused as to what the OP is after. We can't hope an algebraic theory to describe an initial algebra (which is what the hereditary finite sets are), we would need also a suitable induction principle. But would that count as "algebraic"?

Comment: Yeah, it’s not very clear to me either what the OP is after.

Comment: It doesn't sound probable that this theory is algebraizable in the sense that it is algebraic theory. It could be algebraizable in another sense: this theory is the theory of a quasi-variety of algebras.  I would call such a theory ``quasi-algebraic''.

Comment: Well neither $x\notin\emptyset$ nor $z\in x\cup\{y\}\to z\in x\lor z=y$ can be expressed by quasi-identities, as they are not preserved by products (including the empty product, for the former).

Comment: @IoachimDrugus: it would help to know what the larger context of this question is. What are you trying to accomplish? What do you want to do with the theory, once you have it?

Comment: I want to understand what is to 'algebraize set theory' in terms of universal algebra. I learnt from reading 'categorical set theory' that this is not what is called 'algebraic theory' since the algebraic structures used by this theory have infinitary operations. However, this is an algebraic set theory in a wider sense. Thus, the authors had to give up something (finiteness) in order to still algebraize ZF close to 'algebraic theory'.  I suspect, that in terms of universal algebra one also cannot algebraize set theory to obtain an 'algebraic theory'...

Comment: However, I hope, that by giving up some conditions required to be an algebraic theory, one can get a theory close to 'algebraic theory'. What one must give up? I suspect this is the condition that the axioms must be identities. Thus, maybe we must look for quasi-idetities which axiomatize this theory. I chose specifically this theory to learn about algebraization of set theory, because adjunction is the best known operation used for algebraization purposes.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So you more or less randomly suggested $\triangleright$, it's not like you want to *do* something with it, you're just trying to understand what "algebraic" means in the context of set theory? Well, it would have been easier to answer that question directly :-)

Comment: My earlier question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306165/what-is-algebraic-theory-in-the-wide-sense requests a more or less "direct answer". However, this theory having directly to do with algebraization sounds to me also an interesting subject for research.